# Image operation faster in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I am doing non-linear filter operation on an Image in python. If image is of high resolution, it takes very high time to process the image. Can it be done is faster way?
Code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


img = cv.imread('Capture.jpg')
out = cv.normalize(img.astype('float'), None, 0.0, 1.0, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
h, w, c = img.shape
out_img = np.zeros((h, w, c))
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        ma = max(out[i, j])
        mi = min(out[i, j])
        if ma != 0 and mi !=0:
            out_img[i, j] = (mi/ma)*out[i, j]
        else:
            out_img[i, j] = out[i, j]
```

Here I am traversing whole image, Is there a way to make it faster? Thanks

Comment: Might Tensorflow help, particularly if you have a GPU on your computer?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d71/tutorial_py_optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand in your code, let suppose we have a 2d-array(what are you doing with dimension 'c', color channels?)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(4,3)
ma=np.max(x, axis=1)
mi=np.min(x, axis=1)
y=np.zeros((4,3))
ma=np.expand_dims(ma, axis=1)
mi=np.expand_dims(mi, axis=1)
y = x*(ma/mi)
```

Does it suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy vectorization. I believe this would do it:

```py
# ...
h, w, c = img.shape

mi = np.min(img, axis=2)
ma = np.max(img, axis=2)

# there's probably a better way than reshape
ratio = np.reshape([mi / ma] * c, (h, w, c))
mask = np.reshape([(mi != 0) & (ma != 0)] * c, (h, w, c))

out_img = mask * ratio * img + ~mask * img
```